# Passing function into angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, using-directives

I want to pass a function that returns a promise into my directive. Currently I am doing as follows:

Callback created in parent controller:

```
$scope.myCb = function(data) {
   console.log(data);
}
```

Scope of Directive:

```
scope {
    dataCallback: "&"
}
```

It is being passed to the directive as follows:

```
<my-directive data-callback="createCallback"></div>
```

And it is being called in the directive controller as follows:

```
$scope.dataCallback(data)
```

where data is a local variable.

Currently this is not working. The `$scope.dataCallback` is returning `parentGet(scope, locals)` and is not executing any of the code inside of the function.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

https://plnkr.co/edit/ycgFpurlt2MFupPI1LZJ?p=preview

Comment: can you share a plnker with this? What does the function refer to?

Comment: @AbdulFattahPopoola

 https://plnkr.co/edit/ycgFpurlt2MFupPI1LZJ?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

Can not use `data` as start of directive property.